# Google Foobar Doomsday Fuel Challenge IndexError

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, index-error

I was working on a small python challenge where the code was working fine on my laptop but showing index error on line 18 in the online console.
Question is

```
Doomsday Fuel
=============

Making fuel for the LAMBCHOP's reactor core is a tricky process because of the exotic matter involved. It starts as raw ore, then during processing, begins randomly changing between forms, eventually reaching a stable form. There may be multiple stable forms that a sample could ultimately reach, not all of which are useful as fuel. 

Commander Lambda has tasked you to help the scientists increase fuel creation efficiency by predicting the end state of a given ore sample. You have carefully studied the different structures that the ore can take and which transitions it undergoes. It appears that, while random, the probability of each structure transforming is fixed. That is, each time the ore is in 1 state, it has the same probabilities of entering the next state (which might be the same state).  You have recorded the observed transitions in a matrix. The others in the lab have hypothesized more exotic forms that the ore can become, but you haven't seen all of them.

Write a function answer(m) that takes an array of array of nonnegative ints representing how many times that state has gone to the next state and return an array of ints for each terminal state giving the exact probabilities of each terminal state, represented as the numerator for each state, then the denominator for all of them at the end and in simplest form. The matrix is at most 10 by 10. It is guaranteed that no matter which state the ore is in, there is a path from that state to a terminal state. That is, the processing will always eventually end in a stable state. The ore starts in state 0. The denominator will fit within a signed 32-bit integer during the calculation, as long as the fraction is simplified regularly. 

For example, consider the matrix m:
[
  [0,1,0,0,0,1],  # s0, the initial state, goes to s1 and s5 with equal probability
  [4,0,0,3,2,0],  # s1 can become s0, s3, or s4, but with different probabilities
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s2 is terminal, and unreachable (never observed in practice)
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s3 is terminal
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s4 is terminal
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s5 is terminal
]
So, we can consider different paths to terminal states, such as:
s0 -> s1 -> s3
s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s1 -> s4
s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s5
Tracing the probabilities of each, we find that
s2 has probability 0
s3 has probability 3/14
s4 has probability 1/7
s5 has probability 9/14
So, putting that together, and making a common denominator, gives an answer in the form of
[s2.numerator, s3.numerator, s4.numerator, s5.numerator, denominator] which is
[0, 3, 2, 9, 14].

Languages
=========

To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py
To provide a Java solution, edit solution.java

Test cases
==========

Inputs:
    (int) m = [[0, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Output:
    (int list) [7, 6, 8, 21]

Inputs:
    (int) m = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Output:
    (int list) [0, 3, 2, 9, 14]
```

And the code is

```
from itertools import product 
from fractions import Fraction
from functools import reduce
#this is for matrix inversion
def invert(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    inverse = [[Fraction(0) for col in range(n)] for row in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        inverse[i][i] = Fraction(1)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i != j:
                if matrix[i][i] == 0:
                    return False
                ratio = matrix[j][i] / matrix[i][i]
                for k in range(n):
                    inverse[j][k] = inverse[j][k] - ratio * inverse[i][k]
                    matrix[j][k] = matrix[j][k] - ratio * matrix[i][k]
    for i in range(n):
        a = matrix[i][i]
        if a == 0:
            return False
        for j in range(n):
            inverse[i][j] = inverse[i][j] / a
    return inverse
#finding sum of a row in matrix
def sumRow(m, r):
    return sum(m[r])
#subtracting two matrices
def substract(matr_a, matr_b):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(matr_a)):
        tmp = []
        for valA, valB in zip(matr_a[i], matr_b[i]):
            tmp.append(valA - valB)
        output.append(tmp[:])
    return output[:]
#matrix multiplication
def matrixmult(matr_a, matr_b):
    #cols = len(matr_b[0])
    rows = len(matr_b)
    if rows is not 0:
        cols = len(matr_b[0])
    else:
        cols = 0
    resRows = range(len(matr_a))
    rMatrix = [[0] * cols for _ in resRows]
    for idx in resRows:
        for j, k in product(range(cols), range(rows)):
            rMatrix[idx][j] += matr_a[idx][k] * matr_b[k][j]
    if cols is not 0:
        return rMatrix
    else:
        return 0
    # return rMatrix
#gcd to find lcm
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:      
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a
#lcm to find last value of the output
def lcm(a,n):
    ans = a[0]
    for i in range(1,n):
        ans = (a[i]*ans)//gcd(a[i],ans)
    return ans
#main function
def answer(m):
    num = len(m)
    f=[]
    #finding zero rows
    for i in range(0,num):
        j=[]
        j.append(sumRow(m,i))
        j.append(i)
        f.append(j)
    k=0;
    #Fraction Conversion
    for i in range(0,num):
        for j in range(0,num):
            if f[i][0]!=0:
                m[i][j]=Fraction(m[i][j],f[i][0])
    j=[]
    for i in range(0,len(f)):
        if f[i][0].numerator==0:
            j.append(i)
            del m[f[i][1]-k]
            k=k+1
    q=m
    k=[]
    t=0
    e=m
   # print(m)
    q=[]
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        row=[]
        for r in range(0,len(m[0])):
            for t in range(0,len(j)):
                if j[t] is r:
                    row.append(m[i][r])
        q.append(row)
   # print(q)
    t=0;
    w=0;
    e=[]
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        row=[]
        flag=1
        for r in range(0,len(m[0])):
            for t in range(0,len(j)):
                if j[t] is r:
                    flag=0
                    break
            if flag is 1:
                row.append(m[i][r])
        e.append(row)
    #print(e)
    l=[]
    for i in range(0,len(e)):
        k=[]
        for b in range(0,len(e)):
            if i==b:
                k.append(1)
            else:
                k.append(0)
        l.append(k)
    #print(l)
    #print(e)
    l=substract(l,e)
    #print(l)
    l=invert(l)
    r = matrixmult(l,q)
    #print(r)
    if r == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        m =r[0]
    e=[]
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        e.append(m[i].denominator)
    k=lcm(e,len(e))
    e=[]
    for i in range(0,len(m)):
        e.append((m[i].numerator*k)//m[i].denominator)
    e.append(k)
    #print(e)
    return e
#answer (m = [[0, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
#answer (m = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

time left was around 19h please tell me where I am doing mistake I'm absolutely new to python just started coding in python yesterday as dealing with fractions here is easy compared to java.

**Note:** Online console Won't accept numpy library so we have to hard code things like matrix inverse

After testing various cases I found this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\python.py", line 148, in <module>
    answer (m = [[0, 2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
  File "C:\Users\python.py", line 131, in answer
    l=invert(l)
  File "C:\Users\python.py", line 18, in invert
    matrix[j][k] = matrix[j][k] - ratio * matrix[i][k]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Could you please post the full traceback from when you get an error?

Comment: the compiler won't give the full traceback but the error was giving at line 18 just edited the question thanks :)

Comment: I can't think of what might be causing what you are seeing, but you do have a typo in the `invert` function. You have two lines of `return false` that should be `return False`.

Comment: thanks! changed the code but still the error remain same :/

Comment: @FamousJameous Made a small edit in the description please check now

Comment: I took another look, in the specific case you mention, `matrix` on the line that fails is a 3x2 matrix but you use the longer dimension causing the index error. I don't know why the matrix passed to  `invert` isn't square. You should try to figure out why that is happening.

Comment: Markov chain rule

Comment: Yeah I solved that error now there was no errors in the code but it was showing there was a problem while executing your code @FamousJameous

Comment: @RaviKodumuri Which code? `return False`?

Comment: Nope IndexError! Actually inverse wont exist for nonsquare matrices in this case inverse is called for every matrix so I checked whether it is a square or not so it solved the error

Answer (score 0):

That error is generated when the list index you are referencing for the line matrix[j][k] = matrix[j][k] - ratio * matrix[i][k] is not in the the list. I am not quite sure why it is being generated as I tested your code for def inverse(matrix) and it passed all of my test cases. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes! There was no error in the inverse(matrix) function it was doing that job great. But the error was in answer(matrix) function somehow a nonsquare matrix is generating and is passed to that inverse() function so it was generating the error. I solved it by checking the length of row and column of matrix and passing only if it's square matrix